# Why is Magento not outputting the correct number format?

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I have this:

```
<?php 
foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item): 
   if($item->getParentItemId()) continue;
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
$profit = $product->getData('profit');
$totalprofit += $profit['total'];
endforeach;
echo $totalprofit; 
?>
```

But instead of outputting 22.95 it outputs 23

How can I get it to output the correct number?

Comment: Are the values saved as decimals instead of integers?

Comment: I had to revert my codes back as something went wrong. I now have this: <?php foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item): ?>
<?php if($item->getParentItemId()) continue;?>
<?php $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId()); ?>
<?php echo $product->getData('profit'); ?>
<?php endforeach;?> I'm not sure what an integer is right off but this code is giving me the correct values like 22.9800, 12.7809 ...stuff like that. Now I'm trying to add them together.

Comment: Try adding the items by using the $totalprofit variable declared before the foreach: "$totalprofit = 0;".  Then when trying to add the profit:  "$totalprofit = $totalprofit + $profit['total'];".

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up with that works for me:

```
<?php
    $order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order');
    $order->loadByIncrementId(
      Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId()
    );
    $totalData = $order->getData();
    $allitems = $order->getAllVisibleItems();

foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item): 
      if($item->getParentItemId()) continue; 
          $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
          $totalProfit += ((float) $product->getData('profit')) * $item->getQtyOrdered();
endforeach;
?> 
<?php echo $totalProfit; ?>
```